# Replacing (not removing) special char in a String by other char

Tags: java, android, indexof, replaceall

I need to replace `"《br》"` to `"<br>"`.

`replaceAll` does not work, but if I do it in the variable window when debugging ... it works!

Same with `indexOf("《")` , returns -1 but using the variable window returns 12

How can I replace it?

[image: This is what I see in the variable windows when debugging. The same in code does not work.]

[image: This is what I see in the code (check this>: pos1=-1)]

So the question is, how to make it work in the code

Comment: you probably do `string.replaceAll(...)`, but you should re-assign to a result: `string = string.replaceAll(...)`

Comment: Try Evaluate with ASCII code this expression

Answer (score 2):

As String is immutable you are not changing original value of `text` variable. `replaceAll` creates new String with correct value and you have to assign it to variable to use it.

Reference of usage can be found [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall) with some more explanation, but basic usage is:

```
String originalText ="some text with letters to replace";  
String newTextWithReplacedValues = originalText.replaceAll("a","e");//replaces all occurrences of "a" to "e"  
System.out.println(newTextWithReplacedValues);
```

You can see it working in the debugger since `text.replaceAll(...)` returns proper value. It is just not changing original `text` variable.

Comment: May be my question was not clear enough. I now that i must assigned the replacement to a string, But if you see the second image, it shows that pos1 == -1 , meaning it did not found the special char. I did this becouse when assign result of replaceAll to a new string, it did not do the replace. So I check if the special char was found with indexOf. I should explain better the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me replacing just works fine.

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "《br》";
        s = s.replace("《", "<").replace("》", ">");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

《 may not be a single character though since '《' gives an error but "《" works.

This is the [Character documentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)

> The set of characters from U+0000 to U+FFFF is sometimes referred to
>   as the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP). Characters whose code points
>   are greater than U+FFFF are called supplementary characters. The Java
>   platform uses the UTF-16 representation in char arrays and in the
>   String and StringBuffer classes. In this representation, supplementary
>   characters are represented as a pair of char values, the first from
>   the high-surrogates range, (\uD800-\uDBFF), the second from the
>   low-surrogates range (\uDC00-\uDFFF).